# XSL-FO display-align + line-height

Tags: xsl-fo

I have a table, with fixed line-height rows (8mm). When one cell overflow, this cell grow for another 8mm, and my row now 16mm. All was perfect. But now i need do a bottom aligned text. And display-align="after" not working with line-height.

```
        <fo:table-row height="8mm" line-height="8mm" text-align="left" keep-together.within-page="always">
           <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="FORMAT"/>
           </fo:table-cell>
           <fo:table-cell text-align="center" display-align="after">
               <fo:block>
                   test
               </fo:block>
           </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
```

If I remove line-height="8mm", vertical align will work, but i need my row to be              divisible exactly by 8mm.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not see what your issue is, can you post a image of the PDF you are getting ?

Comment: I tested with FOP 1.1 and FOP 2.0, and in both cases the output seems correct. Maybe you could include an example of a *complete table* showing the problem, and / or add *details about the formatter* you are actually using.